# Using Avrocoder for Custom Types with Generics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, avro, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to use AvroCoder to serialise a custom type which is passed around in PCollections in my pipeline. The custom type has a generic field (which currently is a String) When I run the pipeline, I get the AvroTypeException like below probably due to the generic field. Is building and passing the AvroSchema for the object the only way to get around this?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown type: T
 at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:255)
 at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createSchema(ReflectData.java:514)
 at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createFieldSchema(ReflectData.java:593)
 at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData.createSchema(ReflectData.java:472)
 at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:189)
 at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(AvroCoder.java:116)
```

I have also attached my registry code for reference.

```
pipelineCoderRegistry.registerCoder(GenericTypeClass.class, new CoderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Coder<?> create(List<? extends Coder<?>> componentCoders) {
        return AvroCoder.of(GenericTypeClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> getInstanceComponents(Object value) {
        return Collections.singletonList(((GenericTypeClass<Object>) value).key);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You’ve done everything right as far as setting up the [`CoderFactory`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/CoderFactory), but Avro’s [`ReflectData`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/ReflectData.html) mechanism which [`AvroCoder`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder) uses to automatically generate a schema does not work for generic types, as of this writing. This is tracked as issue [AVRO-1571](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1571). See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666618/can-apache-avro-framework-handle-parameterized-types-during-serialization).

In order to allow encoding of `GenericTypeClass<T>` for some particular values of `T`, you are correct that you will have to provide some explicit schema information. There are two ways to proceed:

The first approach is to provide an explicit schema on fields of type `T` within your `GenericTypeClass<T>`, like so:

```java
class GenericTypeClass<T> {
  // Avro requires a no-args constructor
  public GenericTypeClass() {}

  @AvroSchema("[\"string\", \"int\", ...]")
  private T genericField;
}
```

The drawback is that it is limited to a finite, static union schema, and requires manually inlining the JSON schema for more complex values of `T`.

The second approach is to provide an explicit schema when you build an `AvroCoder` in your `CoderFactory`, and provide this schema to [`AvroCoder.of(Class, Schema)`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder#of-java.lang.Class-org.apache.avro.Schema-).

```java
pipelineCoderRegistry.registerCoder(GenericTypeClass.class, new CoderFactory() {
  @Override
  public Coder<?> create(List<? extends Coder<?>> componentCoders) {
      return AvroCoder.of(
          GenericTypeClass.class
          schemaFromCoder(componentCoders.get(0)));
  }

  ...
});
```

This will mostly revolve around converting a `Coder<T>` into a schema for `T`. This should be easy for basic types and manageable for POJOs that `ReflectData` supports. It does also provide a hook for ad hoc support of more difficult cases.

Comment: Thanks. I feel the second option is much cleaner as well in my case. As for converting the Coder to a Schema, should I provide the Schema for the entire object or only the generic type within the object (which in my case is a String)? I could not figure out how to perform the conversion from the Coder...

Comment: The schema passed in a call such as AvroCoder.of(GenericTypeClass.class, schema) should be a full schema for the GenericTypeClass<T>.

Comment: So I tried using @AvroSchema("[\"string\"]) over the parameterized type in the generic class defn but now, when I use it against AvroCoder in dataflow, I get an error like this

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.package.GenericType.()\n\tat org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newInstance(SpecificData.java:316)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.package.GenericType.()\n\tat java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)\n\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)\n\t`

Comment: There is so little documentation for AvroCoder that it is extremely hard to understand whats going wrong here. It looks like its complaining about a missing default constructor for the generic type, may be?

Comment: Avro requires a no-argument constructor. You can read more about the requirements at the javadoc for [org.apache.avro.reflect](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/package-summary.html).

Comment: Note that the documentation you're missing is for *Avro*, not for *AvroCoder*. You can tell where the error is from the stack trace you posted. It's in the `org.apache.avro...` code.