# Serializing generic class with provided schema using AvroCoder

Tags: java, generics, avro, google-cloud-dataflow

Let's make a simple class.

```
class IntValue {
    private int data;

    IntValue() {}
    IntValue(int data) { this.setData(data); }

    int getData() { return this.data; }
    void setData(int data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

And a thin generic wrapper:

```
class Snapshot<T> {
    private T value;

    Snapshot<T> () {}

    T getValue() { return value; }
    void setValue(T value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

Next let's make a helper to obtain wrapper's schema.

```
private static Schema buildSnapshotSchema(Schema valueSchema) {
    return SchemaBuilder.record("Snapshot")
            .namespace("com.stackoverflow.primer")
            .fields()
            .name("value").type(valueSchema).noDefault()
            .endRecord();
}
```

Lastly, I would like to create AvroCoder with explicit schema in the same way as it was created in [Using Avrocoder for Custom Types with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137264/using-avrocoder-for-custom-types-with-generics)

```
AvroCoder.of(Snapshot.class, buildSnapshotSchema(AvroCoder.of(IntValue.class).getSchema())
```

As a result...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to get field data from class null
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.getField(AvroCoder.java:710)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.checkRecord(AvroCoder.java:548)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.doCheck(AvroCoder.java:477)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.recurse(AvroCoder.java:453)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.checkRecord(AvroCoder.java:567)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.doCheck(AvroCoder.java:477)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.recurse(AvroCoder.java:453)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder$AvroDeterminismChecker.check(AvroCoder.java:430)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.<init>(AvroCoder.java:189)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.of(AvroCoder.java:144)
at com.stackoverflow.primer.GenericPipeline.main(GenericPipeline.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

It happened in AvroDeterminismChecker when it failed to obtain field "data" from an instance of Object. This makes sense, but why it doesn't use provided schema to reconstruct the object? How can an instance of AvroCoder be created in this case?

UPDATE

Found another post with similar problem, but it looks like it wasn't be resolved... [Dataflow output parameterized type to avro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886734/dataflow-output-parameterized-type-to-avro-file)

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace rather than only the error message?

Comment: @jkff just FYI the version of SDK is 1.9.0

Comment: @jkff I've update the post with full stack trace, could you check it again please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and pasted your example into the code of [AvroCoderTest](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/AvroCoderTest.java) in the master branch of Apache Beam and the test does not fail with this exception:

```
static class IntValue {
  private int data;

  IntValue() {}
  IntValue(int data) { this.setData(data); }

  int getData() { return this.data; }
  void setData(int data) { this.data = data; }
}
static class Snapshot<T> {
  private T value;

  Snapshot() {}

  T getValue() { return value; }
  void setValue(T value) { this.value = value; }
}
private static Schema buildSnapshotSchema(Schema valueSchema) {
  return SchemaBuilder.record("Snapshot")
      .namespace("blah")
      .fields()
      .name("value").type(valueSchema).noDefault()
      .endRecord();
}

@Test
public void testStackOverflowPost() throws Exception {
  AvroCoder.of(Snapshot.class, buildSnapshotSchema(AvroCoder.of(IntValue.class).getSchema()));
}
```

Perhaps the issue has been fixed?

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting, looks like this case was covered with tests [few months ago](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/9c8dc4fe920618253b425f0d998f8d63552ec358). Looking at the version of AvroCoder in [Dataflow SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) it seems that the change was not backported. Does it mean that currently there is no way to encode generic classes using Dataflow SDK?

Comment: This is possible - Beam is intended to become *the* SDK for Dataflow, and we tend to backport ourselves only critical fixes - guess we missed this one. Are you able to use the Beam SDK? Otherwise, please feel free to send a pull request to Dataflow with the backport - it will likely be reviewed and merged swiftly.

Answer (score 0):

Never used AvroCoder, but thats a common problem with generics in other frameworks as well. This is usually solved by a super type token. AvroCoder has a method that takes a type token (in that case TypeDescriptor).

I have not tried this code, but it has some likelihood of working.

```
AvroCoder.of( new TypeDescriptor<Snapshot<InvValue>>(){}).of( buildSnapshotSchema(AvroCoder.of(IntValue.class).getSchema());
```

Comment: I've already tried this approach, but unsuccessfully. It leads to:
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown type: T`

Answer (score 0):

The final note:
up to version 1.9 Dataflow SDK **does not support** using AvroCoder on generics. The error occurs when AvroCoder constructor tries to guess if the result is deterministic or not.

The issue was [resolved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-359) for Apache Beam in Jule'16. After Apache Beam v0.2-incubating AvroCoder **always instantiates not-deterministic coder for generics**. For some reasons it was not backported to Dataflow SDK. Following @jkff advice I've created a [PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/531) to Dataflow. If the maintainers decide to apply it – Dataflow SDK v1.10 will support generics.

The good news is there is already SDK v.2.01-beta which is light proxy to Apache Beam v0.4.0 which supports generics and have numerous additions. The transition demands some code updates but it is definitely worth it.